# Display current date on webpage - is it better to use javascript or php?

Tags: javascript, php, date

I want to display the current date(-time) on an webpage. I see two possibilities:
(1) Using php, e.g.

```
<?php echo date('Y-m-d');?>
```

(2) … or javascript, e.g.

```
<div>
  <script>document.write(new Date().toLocaleDateString());</script>
</div>
```

Is there a clear "better" way to do this or have both ways their own pros and cons so I have to decide on the setup?

Comment: If you want to keep the time up-to-date (user could sit and look at a page for quite a while) then javascript is your route

Comment: If you want to show the date and time of your server, you should use your server

Comment: To better answer this question, perhaps you can clarify "current time". Time where the server resides, vs time where the user is sitting. I suppose if you include a time zone market (such as UTC) then it doesn't matter, but the user might want time to reflect his/her time zone. If you want the time to continuously update, or to reflect The time at page load. The Purpose of the time being displayed might change the answer?

Answer (score 3):

If you use JavaScript, you'll be relying on the client's machine having an accurate time. While most clients nowadays *do* have accurate time, it's not guaranteed, and it's good to present a consistent, accurate interface for all users on all devices.

If you use the *server*'s timestamp, and you make sure the server's time is and remains accurate, you *will* have consistency. (It doesn't have to be generated in PHP - use whatever language you want which can get the information on the server to the client.)

If you have elements whose time needs to be updated periodically, consider calculating the *difference* between the server's (good) time and the client's (possibly inaccurate) time, and using that difference in JavaScript to figure out how much to modify the client-generated times by. (I believe this is what Stack Exchange does - it sends a `serverTime` timestamp in the page response and displays timestamps accurately as a result (for example, with comments) even if the user's `new Date` returns something completely inaccurate.

Answer (score 0):

That's not fair to compare JavaScript vs PHP, as they both have different purposes for web-site development languages. PHP is a server-side scripting language while JavaScript is a client-side scripting language. and the main reason is that PHP doesn’t execute within the browser whereas Javascript executes within the browser. Because if your system date is incorrect your website will show the wrong date.

But if you use PHP your code will collect the information where your website is located. So I'm assuming that your web application definitely shows the correct date.

Comment: But wouldn't it show the time that the server is configured to show, which is not necessarily the time zone that the user, the person visiting the webpage, is in? Also server configuration does not necessarily match the physical location of the server. So depending on the purpose of the webpage, some sort of calculation might need to be done regardless. Reading the user's locality / time setting might be needed, depending of course on the purpose of the time shown. If it's strictly the server time that's of interest, then this is more straight forward.